# Can't authenticate and navigate to next activity using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I am facing a problem I am working on a app which requires login and it then navigates to a new screen .I am unable to navigate to new screen.

Here is the code:

***Main.dart***

```html
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
          context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return PatientList();
    }
    return HomePage();
  }
}
```

This class mainly contains the authentication code

***HomePage.dart***

```html
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/loginHeader.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FadeAnimation(
                          1.8,
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                                      blurRadius: 20.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 10))
                                ]),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                          bottom: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.grey[100]))),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: emailController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: "Email",
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintText: "Email or Phone number",
                                      hintStyle:
                                          TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: passwordController,
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Password",
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintText: "Password",
                                      hintStyle:
                                          TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 100, right: 100, top: 20, bottom: 20),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                                email: emailController.text.trim(),
                                password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                              );
                        },
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Text("Login".toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                      ),
                      ClipOval(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            gotoForgotPassword(BuildContext context) {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => ForgotPassword()),
                              );
                            }
                            gotoForgotPassword(context);
                          },
                          child: Text("Forgot Password"),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

This class is the login & forgot password screen this is the activity which should navigate to the next activity when authenticated correctly

***PatientList***

```html
class PatientList extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Container(
            height: 174,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/patient_list.png'),
            )),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 128,
                  child: Text(
                    'Patient List',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            gotoRegister(BuildContext context) {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Register()),
              );
            }
            gotoRegister(context);
          },
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the activity which should open when we enter username and password.

***AuthenticationService***

```html
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);

  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.idTokenChanges();


  /*Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }*/

  Future<String> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return "Signed in";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }

/*
  Future<String> signUp({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return "Signed up";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
*/
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @fartem NO just can't navigate

Comment: What is `User` model in `context.watch<User>()`?

Comment: @fartem i am getting this in my log: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

Comment: It is this an actual model?